# Windows Mobile Gradient Fill Button - UserControl vs Subclassing Button

Tags: windows-mobile, user-controls, design-time

I've started looking at Windows Mobile development and I'm struggling to make a pleasing UI using the default controls (they really are ugly). I've looked at a handful of UI 'frameworks' and they are either costly or complex (my needs are simple).

So I've decided to write my own controls. Taking a rounded rectangle gradient filled Button as an example I'd like your thoughts on creating a UserControl vs Subclassing Button.

Good design time support is important to me so I can layout the UI easily. I've played with both alternatives and I've so far failed to get design time painting of the button to work

Thanks

Dave

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I personally would subclass the button. If you create a user control you are going to have to expose every proprty on the button you might want to customize.

Take a look at this MSDN article for sub classing a button with a gradient 
fill
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229661.aspx